# Dynamically generate LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ef-database-first

I have a GetX(DataTableParameters model) function where model.Order contains Column (which can be 1 (Id), 2 (Name) etc..) and Dir (which can be 'asc' or 'desc'). Then i have a LINQ query where i would like to dynamically generate OrderByDescending or OrderBy and r => r.Id or r => r.Name depending on model values.

```
DbContext.Users.Where(r => r.FirstName.Contains(model.Search.Value) ||
                            r.LastName.Contains(model.Search.Value) ||
                           r.Email.Contains(model.Search.Value))
.**OrderByDescending(r => r.Id)**.Skip(model.Start).Take(model.Length);
```

Can this be done? If so can anyone point me in the right direction. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works almost exactly as you typed it. Each LINQ *function* returns a *result*. You don't have to chain all of them, just put the result from `Where()` into a variable, apply whatever `OrderBy` method you want to it, then proceed wiht `OrderBy`'s result and apply the rest of the methods

Comment: Did that and was stuck with a lot of if's or switch cases which i wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Dynamic Linq**, there are a few libraries that help you working with it. I'm using this and it looks great, look here for more info

- https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

It's a fork from an older library that was suddenly removed and it allows you to write dynamic code like

```
var result = myQuery
    .OrderBy("Field1 asc")
    .Select("new (Field1, Field2)");
```

take a look at http://web.archive.org/web/20160109203827/http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/ (documentation for old library) to have a good overview.

Comment: Just what i was looking for, this will be easy to implement since i don't have a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using DataTables. I have the same scenario and wrote some code that leverages the [PagedList nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/) to provide paged, sortable JSON data for DataTables.

The usage looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetJson(DataTablesParam param)
{
    using (var context = new SalesContext())
    {
        return context.Sales
            .TrustedSortToPagedList(param.ToPagingCriteria())
            .Select(s => new SaleViewModel(s))
            .ToDataTableResult(param.Draw);
    }
}
```

In javascript I include this parameter in the DataTable configuration:

```
ajax: {
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "@Url.Action("GetJson")",
    type: "POST",
    data: function(d) {
        // add extra query parameters here
        d.startDate = $("#startDate").val();
        d.endDate = $("#endDate").val();
        return JSON.stringify(d);
    },
},
```

The full code is available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanohs/55d65d35feac047f0371).

Comment: This is really nice, i'll reimplement it like this when i get the chance, for now i'll just take Linq. Dinamic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query=DbContext
  .Users
  .Where(r => r.FirstName.Contains(model.Search.Value) ||
              r.LastName.Contains(model.Search.Value) ||
              r.Email.Contains(model.Search.Value));

switch(Model.Order)
{
  case 1:
    query=(Model.Dir=="asc")?
      query.OrderBy(q=>q.id):
      query.OrderByDescending(q=>q.id);
    break;
  case 2:
    query=(Model.Dir=="asc")?
      query.OrderBy(q=>q.Name):
      query.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Name);
    break;
}
query=query
  .Skip(Model.Start)
  .Take(Model.Length);
```

Comment: I was doing it just like that but wanted a simpler solution. Thank you tho